# Multi Phrase Query does not find my documents

Tags: solr

As part of an upgrade plan from version 6.2.1, I'm setting up a new Solr (7.6.0). 
Surprisingly, one of our simple tests failed - inserting a document with some text and then trying to search for it.

The text that was inserted is:

> I will think about it.

Request handler configuration:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">    
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">20</int>
       <str name="df">text_en</str>
       <str name="hl.fragsize">100000</str>
       <str name="hl.maxAnalyzedChars">100000</str>
     </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

This is how the field is configured:

```xml
<field name="text_en" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />


<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"  words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"  words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**"will"** and **"it"** appears in stopwords_en.txt file.

According to *Analysis* in the Admin Web App, those are the final tokens that are inserted into the index:

```
text:     i i_will will_think think about about_it  
position: 1    1       2        3     4      4
```

Search for `text_en:"I will think about it"` doesn't find the document.

Strange thing is, the query `"I will think think about it"` does work...

Using *debugQuery*, I noticed a difference compared to our current version.
6.2.1 is using `MultiPhraseQuery`
7.6.0 is using `SpanNearQuery`

In version 6.2.1:

```
"rawquerystring":"text_en:\"I will think about it\"",
    "querystring":"text_en:\"I will think about it\"",
    "parsedquery":"MultiPhraseQuery(text_en:\"(i i_will) will_think think (about about_it)\")", ...
```

In 7.6.0 (btw, also in 7.5.0):

```
"rawquerystring":"text_en:\"I will think about it\"",
    "querystring":"text_en:\"I will think about it\"",
    "parsedquery":"SpanNearQuery(spanNear([spanOr([spanNear([text_en:i, text_en:will_think], 0, true), spanNear([text_en:i_will, text_en:think], 0, true)]), text_en:about_it], 0, true))", ...
```

Comment: Please share your default query handler. After all I read there appears to be a difference. You will find this in your **solrconfig.xml** of your collection/core.

Comment: @cheffe Thanks for your help, I've edited my question and added the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the culprit.
Sharing it to support future googlers.
There was a mistake in the field configuration in schema.xml file.
In the "query" analyzer, instead of "CommonGramsFilterFactory", it should be "CommonGrams**Query**FilterFactory".